# I am trying to use template metaprogramming to find the greatest common divisor, but the compiler reports an error

Tags: c++, template-meta-programming

I am trying to find the greatest common divisor using template metaprogramming, and encountered some problems during the process. Please see the code, errors and other information:

C++ code:

```
#include <iostream>
namespace meta{
    namespace _algorithm{
        template<bool size_,long long A_,long long B_>
        struct GCD{
            static const long long value;
        };
        template<bool size_,long long A_>
        struct GCD<size_,A_,0>{
            static const long long value=A_;
        };
        template<bool size_,long long B_>
        struct GCD<size_,0,B_>{
            static const long long value=B_;
        };
        template<long long A_,long long B_>
        struct GCD<false,A_,B_>{
            static const long long value=GCD<false,B_,A_%B_>::value;
        };
        template<long long A_,long long B_>
        struct GCD<true,A_,B_>{
            static const long long value=GCD<true,B_%A_,A_>::value;
        };
    }
}
using namespace std;
int main(){
    cout<<meta::_algorithm::GCD<1346<540,1346,540>::value<<endl;
}
```

Operating system: `Linux(Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS)`

Compiler: `GCC10.1.0`

Compile command: `$ g++ main.cpp -std=20`

Error message:

```
basictype.hpp: In instantiation of ‘const long long int meta::_algorithm::GCD<false, 8, 2>::value’:
basictype.hpp:26:63:   recursively required from ‘const long long int meta::_algorithm::GCD<false, 540, 266>::value’
basictype.hpp:26:63:   required from ‘const long long int meta::_algorithm::GCD<false, 1346, 540>::value’
basictype.hpp:127:53:   required from here
basictype.hpp:26:63: 错误：ambiguous template instantiation for ‘struct meta::_algorithm::GCD<false, 2, 0>’
   26 |             static const long long value=GCD<false,B_,A_%B_>::value;
      |                                                               ^~~~~
basictype.hpp:17:16: 附注：备选是： ‘template<bool size_, long long int A_> struct meta::_algorithm::GCD<size_, A_, 0> [with bool size_ = false; long long int A_ = 2]’
   17 |         struct GCD<size_,A_,0>{
      |                ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
basictype.hpp:25:16: 附注：         ‘template<long long int A_, long long int B_> struct meta::_algorithm::GCD<false, A_, B_> [with long long int A_ = 2; long long int B_ = 0]’
   25 |         struct GCD<false,A_,B_>{
      |                ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
basictype.hpp:26:63: 错误：嵌套名指定中使用了不完全的类型‘meta::_algorithm::GCD<false, 2, 0>’
   26 |             static const long long value=GCD<false,B_,A_%B_>::value;
      |                                                               ^~~~~
```

Does anyone know why this is happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Too much code and compiler does not know which template specialization to use. But first template param can be omitted.
Let's assume that first number is always bigger and keep this assumption during all instantiations:

```
#include <iostream>

template<long long A, long long B> struct GCD;

template<long long A> struct GCD<A,0> {
  static const long long value=A;
};

template<long long A,long long B> struct GCD {
  static const long long value=GCD<B,A%B>::value;
};

int main(){
  std::cout << GCD<1989,867>::value << std::endl;
}
```

Additionally you may write another meta-code which will swap A and B prior passing to GCD if second value is bigger than first one;

Answer (score 0):

```
    template<long long A_,long long B_, bool ABigger=(A_>=B_)>
    struct GCD;
    template<long long A_>
    struct GCD<A_,0, true>{
        static const long long value=A_;
    };
    template<long long B_>
    struct GCD<0,B_, false>{
        static const long long value=B_;
    };
    template<long long A_,long long B_>
    struct GCD<A_,B_,true>{
        static const long long value=GCD<A_%B_, B_>::value;
    };
    template<long long A_,long long B_>
    struct GCD<A_,B_,false>{
        static const long long value=GCD<A_,B_%A_>::value;
    };
```